# How to use snapd with sysVinit?

Tags: snap, mx-linux

I want to test anbox on mxlinux to see if it can run some of the android apps I use in a decent way. The problem is that anbox uses snapd, and these two work only with Systemd.

I tried working with Systemd, but it's a disaster. If the computer for some reason shuts down unexpectedly, on the next boot it doesn't even start the PC.

For this reason, I would like to know, how do I use snapd with sysvinit?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. Snap is based on isolation, mount and container execution services offered by systemd.

You need a service that manages cgroups, something to coordinate shared namespaces, something that makes it possible for unprivileged users to mount archives, and something that manages runtime of these containerized applications. Systemd offers facilities for all that, sysvinit is a pure startup system from the eighties/nineties and offers none of these features of a modern Linux-based operating, which snapd relies on.

The symptoms you described only very unlikely have something to do with systemd, so I think going for the niche init system that sysvinit is in 2023 was probably a bit counterproductive in terms of getting a system that just works. In any case, the snapd people are repeatedly on record saying that they don't plan on supporting non-systemd systems, and that whole it's not impossible, they'd expect the required workarounds to be substantial to close to reimplemtation of parts of systemd.

---

Bit of venting here, definitely not aimed at you personally. But researching what the developers actual said about that topic reminded me of a very ugly pattern you find all over the internet. So I had to "write this is my chest":

When you read threads like [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/installing-and-running-snaps-without-systemd/3949/5), you'll notice that the snapd folks are quite friendly and productive, and like to help the users that really are working on making the subset of features of snapd work that might be realistic without systemd. But it seems to be a law of the internet that in every such thread, the people that just demand that some software works without the dependency that the software was based on, become the loudest voices without bringing actual expertise. And the developers, who were trying to help the people actually trying to make something work that might not have had the full feature set you would need to run, say, well-integrated graphical applications or well-isolated servers, can't keep up, and lose the ability to actually work with them.

That's a bit of a curse of the no-systemd crowd: if the systemd haters were a bit less time-consuming towards developers without contribution, a lot of things that for good reason depend on systemd might by now have feasible alternative backends. Generally, as a FOSS maintainer, your energy can be very rapidly depleted by people trying to make you support their "special" system, consuming the time you could have built something that helps the  majority of people.
That's definitely not to say I don't think MX Linux and similar efforts aren't good - I think it's very important that we don't monopolize the roles that systemd fills. It's just that that is a *positive* reason to do it - and whenever one even mentions that something relies on systemd, a wave of negativity obliterates one's inbox. And that's for something that basically all major distros decided was the right thing to do, ten years ago already!

Comment: Thank you very much for your honest answer. What you say about the systemd phobia is true; But I myself tested systemd and I can confirm that it is inferior to sysvinit. This last one may be from the stone age years but it does the job well. I imagine that other users have discovered similar flaws and that is why they categorically state: no systemd!!!.

Comment: In my case if I have to choose between snapd and sysvinit. I choose sysvinit; because it's not good to have to restore your system with a livecd just because modern systemd doesn't know how to start the system after an abrupt shutdown (with systemd it happened to me three times).

Comment: That sounds totally not like the actual causal chain. Systemd's bootability is quite robust. (in fact, falling back to a known-good boot configuration in case of failure is one of the advantages of systemd-boot) Something else went fundamentally wrong with your system, most likely. What I see repeatedly is that users think it's systemd at fault when systemd is just the bringer of bad news. And as sorry as I am for being so blunt, that would be the more likely explanation here than "systemd refuses to boot because it's fragile". It really isn't.